# CSS Float is making the div content go outside?

Tags: css

i am displaying the images in **Bootstrap Modal Popup** in form of a Grid-view but when i apply the CSS on the Particular DIV Tag, it bring the Images outside the DIV Tag. Below is the Total Code:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .food_img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#today_images').empty();
    $.getJSON('api/gallery/today_photo.php', function(data) {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
        var foodImg = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
            foodImg = '<div class="food_img"><img src="' + val.pic + '" class="img-thumbnail thumb m-r" width="100" height="100"/><span>' + "Image" + '</span></div>';
            $('#today_images').append(foodImg);
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="PeopleJoin" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><font color="#53B567"><i class="fa fa-group"></i></font>&nbsp;People Join</h4>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span id="today_images"></span>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can fine the image in Below URL.

http://s18.postimg.org/6412rngpl/img.png

but when i remove the **Float Tag** then it become Listview but all the images come inside the Popup Window. you can find the image in below URL

http://s9.postimg.org/zcbi6h1r3/img_1.png

so any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: **@leftside** this is the HTML

<div class="food_img"><img src="' IMAGE_LINK'" class="img-thumbnail thumb m-r" width="100" height="100"/><span>Image Heading</span></div

Comment: **@Xufox** Yes i do try already. but still same.

Comment: **@Xufox** i just update my post. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply:

```css
#today_images{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try it with the other containers as well: `.modal-content`, `.modal-body`, etc.

And change

```
<span id="today_images"></span>
```

to a `div`:

```
<div id="today_images"></div>
```

---

Here’s a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phqp05qe/2/) of the `overflow: hidden;` behavior. Go to the JSFiddle or click <kbd>Show code snippet</kbd> and then <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> here. Check the checkbox to apply the CSS rule.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('today_images').style.overflow = this.checked ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
.food_img {
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 20px;
}
#today_images {
  background: #444;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>It is sort of weird, but it works.</p>
<p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />Apply <code>overflow: hidden;</code> to wrapper <code>#today_images</code>.</label>
</p>
<div id="today_images">
  <div class="food_img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?0" alt="" /> <span>Image</span>

  </div>
  <div class="food_img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?1" alt="" /> <span>Image</span>

  </div>
  <div class="food_img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?2" alt="" /> <span>Image</span>

  </div>
  <div class="food_img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?3" alt="" /> <span>Image</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative to all of this is to replace `float: left;` completely with `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;`. You get far more intuitive results this way.

Comment: **@Xufox** i have update the full code in my post. **Overflow:hidden** is not working for me.

Comment: **@Xufox** Yes now OK Already. Thanks Bro  One more thing that how we can put Scroll in Bootstrap Modal Popup Window

Comment: Please ask a new question and avoid follow-up questions in comments. Although I know about the `overflow: hidden` thing, I’m no expert in Bootstrap. If it _isn’t_ by applying `overflow: scroll` to some container, then I can’t really help you.